# Access images contained within Solution Explorer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to access some images I've copied into a folder within Solution Explorer.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to access them programmatically.  The only other question I found that appeared similar was not answered.  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using VB 2010 Express Edition.  The folder name is 'Images'.  The image name is 'checked.png'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you put them as resources, you cannot.  They are just like any other source file in your application.

Import them as a resource, and then you'll be good to go.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319291